# Using pyspark groupBy with a custom function in agg

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to groupBy my spark df with custom agg function:

```py
def gini(list_of_values):
    sth is processing here
    return number output
```

[image]

I would like to get sth like that:

```py
df.groupby('activity')['mean_event_duration_in_hours].agg(gini)
```

Could you please help me to resolve this tackle?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a [`udf`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html) like so:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType

def gini(list_of_values):
    # sth is processing here
    return number_output

udf_gini = F.udf(gini, FloatType())

df.groupby('activity')\
    .agg(F.collect_list("mean_event_duration_in_hours").alias("event_duration_list"))\
    .withColumn("gini", udf_gini(F.col("event_duration_list")))
```

Or define gini as a UDF like this:

```
@udf(returnType=FloatType())
def gini(list_of_values):
    # sth is processing here
    return number_output

df.groupby('activity')\
    .agg(F.collect_list("mean_event_duration_in_hours").alias("event_duration_list"))\
    .withColumn("gini", gini(F.col("event_duration_list")))
```